# Issue using flexslider with sync and startAt

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I worked with 2 FlexSliders on sync and everything goes fine, than I put the a 'startAt' parameter and the slider stop to work after first change, no alerts on FF debugger, the Nav slider simply stop and the other still working fine.

The JS code is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
// The slider being synced must be initialized first
  $('.carousel').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: true,
  slideshow: false,
  itemWidth: 112,
  itemMargin: 5,
  maxItems: 4,
  startAt: 2,
  asNavFor: '.flexslider'
  });

$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: true,
  slideshow: false,
  startAt: 2,
  maxItems: 4,
  sync: ".carousel"
  });
});
```

And here is the "almost" [working page].[1](http://pepperbox.com.br/NewPepper/caixas.php?caixa=soft)
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you paste your html code ?

Answer (score 3):

Solution found :)

I had the same problem, flexslider worked fine on firefox, no error, but stayed stuck after the first animation.

I finally solved it by changing the animationDuration property in the slider. If it is set to 0-> it doens't work set to 1 or any other value-> it works again.

No idea why, but finally it works ! hope it will help people around.

Lisa.

Answer (score 0):

For these out there who has this problem - just update flexslider (download latest version) :)